# Response Ajax в laravel

Tags: php, laravel

У меня есть страница, на которой три поля. Данные в контроллер отправляются при помощи Ajax. Мне их нужно провалидировать. Но вопрос в том как мне отправить обратно два ответа json - если были ошибки и html - если ошибок не было?

```
$.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: 'getData',
            data: {
                city1: $('#cities1').val(),
                city2: $('#cities2').val(),
                date: $('#datetime').val()
            },
            dataType: 'json',
            beforeSend: function () {
                $("div#Request").empty();
                $('#Request').append('<div class="d-flex justify-content-center mt-3">\n' +
                    '  <div class="spinner-border" role="status">\n' +
                    '    <span class="sr-only">Loading...</span>\n' +
                    '  </div><p class="mt-1 ml-3">Поиск маршрутов . . .</p>\n' +
                    '</div>');
            },
            success: function (response) {
                setTimeout(function() {
                    $("div#Request").empty();
                    $('#Request').append(response);
                }, delay);
            }
        });
```

Метод в контроллере:

```
$validator = \Validator::make($request->all(), [
            'city1' => 'required',
            'city2' => 'required',
            'date' => 'required'
        ]);

        if ($validator->fails()) {
            return response()->json($validator->messages());
        }

        return view('layouts/routes');
```

Как это можно сделать?

Comment: у вас есть методы success и error используйте их

Comment: Мне не подходит такой вариант.
Мне с сервера нужно вернуть или JSON, или HTML, в зависимости от параметров запроса (если поля были пустые, вернуть JSON, а если нет, тогда сгенерировать html на сервере и вернуть её)